# How to use TextInputLayout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

This is the .XML code for email, similar is for password and other fields.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edittxt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#f1f2f6"
            android:hint="Email">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:typeface="sans" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Now, I am using it in a Java file like this. Even when I display the full name it shows some id stored rather than the actual name.

```
fullname = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.editxt_fullname);
```

and for the register button click, this is what I am doing.

```
     btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
        
                        String user = fullname.toString`btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
        
                        String user = fullname.toString();
    ();
```

When I display the user just to see what it is storing, it shows some id, not the user name. What is the issue? First I was getting the casting error now I am getting invalid text instead of text I am entering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're directly converting `fullname` to the string using.

```
String user = fullname.toString();
```

Which is wrong because `fullname` is `TextInputLayout`.

To get a text from `TextInputLayout` you need to use:

```
String user = fullname.getEditText().getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextInputLayout to show an error to the user. It seems what you want to do is get the text from the input field, which is the EditText. What you need to do is give the EditText an id, and then reference it in your Java code, instead of the TextInputLayout.
So you can move your id from the TextInputLayout and put it on the EditText instead like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#f1f2f6"
        android:hint="Email">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittxt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:background="@color/light_grey"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:typeface="sans" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And then reference it in your Java code.

```
fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editxt_fullname);
```